# What is the rule for using the definite article in front of a name?

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

What is the rule on the basis of which there is a definite article in front of the name of a man-made object such as the Challenger or the Titan?

Comment: Named ships and other modes of transport are usually given the definite article, but this can be omitted. c.f. these quotations from Patrick O'Brian's _The Reverse of the Medal_ - "I am on my way to buy the _Surprise_." "To think you are the owner of _Surprise_!"

Comment: Does this answer your question, Ja? [Why does English use definite articles before certain proper nouns, such as the names of ships?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169970/why-does-english-use-definite-articles-before-certain-proper-nouns-such-as-the) Or this? [necessary and unnecessary articles for proper nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161463/necessary-and-unnecessary-articles-for-proper-nouns/162166#162166)  ...

Comment: Or this? [definite article before schools colleges and universities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/definite-article-before-schools-colleges-and-universities) // There are many related threads on ELU. The fact that there are so many suggests strongly that usage is idiosyncratic ('the Arsenal' and 'Arsenal' are both common for the football team, for example) and needs checking in individual cases. Answers in the threads support this view.

Answer (score 1):

Basically , there are 3 Cases , though variations & exceptions are inevitable :

**(1 : THE )** When the "creator/owner/maker" names it with "the" , then "the" can not be a choice to the "users".
Eg Naming race horses like "THE Mars Rover" or "THE Voyager". We can not use "A" here. It might be ok to leave out the "THE" in Quick Commentary.

**(2 : THE or no article )** When the "creator/owner/maker" makes a Single Item , without naming it with "the" , then "the" is a choice to the "users".
Eg Government building "Pentagon" , which may be also called "The Pentagon" , but never "A Pentagon" : We can not use "A" , while there is Single Instance of that.

**(3 : THE or no article or A)** When the "creator/owner/maker" makes a line of Items eg in a factory , then "the" & "A" & "no Article" will be choices to the "users" , based on Context.
Eg Company making "Toyota" Cars in factory manufacturing line : "I have a Toyota" , "The Toyota is ubiquitous in my village" , "I always choose Toyota" , "A Toyota [ meaning : in general ] can take you home" , "The [ meaning : My ] Toyota was undergoing maintenance yesterday , hence I came by taxi" , "Toyota has won the race"

Here , variations & exceptions to the general guidelines are inevitable.